# Swapping data in Angular UI-Grid, new columns not visible when changing dataset externally

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I've got a query tool I've been working on, which has an angular form that is filled out, and then when it's submitted it uses AJAX which returns JSON, which is then rendered into [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/), that JSON response looks like

```
{
"success": true,
"message": "",
"columns": ["first_name", "last_name", "company", "employed"]
"results": [
    {first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith", company: "Abc Inc", employed: true},
    {first_name: "Johnny", last_name: "Rocket", company: "Abc Inc", employed: true}]
}
```

I'm working on both the PHP and angular so I have full control over this JSON response if need be. I'm running into an issue when my JSON response from a first AJAX call is rendered, and then I run another, seperate AJAX call on the same page and **get a new data set: this new data set does not render any of the columns that were not in the original data set**. This is hugely problematic as the table is essentially cleared when none of the columns are the same, and I often need to load completely different data into ui-grid in this single page app.

When the JSON is recieved I simply bind the `jsonResult.results` to the old `$scope.myData` variable that ui-grid is bound to.

I've made [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BtxcXPZ06zvHuNFQczMv?p=preview) isolating this issue. A dataset with a "punk" column is loaded, and then clicking "swap data" will try to load a dataset with "employee" column instead of "punk". I've so far looked into directives that will refresh or reload when the $scope.myData variable changes using $watch, and looked at finding something like $scope.columnDefs to let ui-grid know. Relatively new to angular and javascript so directives are still a bit over my head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have updated your plunker slightly:

```
$scope.swapData = function() {
  if ($scope.gridOpts.data === data1) {
    $scope.gridOpts.columnDefs = [
      { name:'firstName' },
      { name:'lastName' },
      { name:'company' },
      { name:'employee' }
    ];
    $scope.gridOpts.data = data2;
    //punk column changes to employee
  }
  else {
    $scope.gridOpts.columnDefs = [
      { name:'firstName' },
      { name:'lastName' },
      { name:'company' },
      { name:'punk' }
    ];
    $scope.gridOpts.data = data1;
    //employee column changes to punk
  }
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/OFt86knctJxcbtf2MwYI?p=preview

Since you have the columns in your json, it should be fairly easy to do.

Comment: That does change the column header titles! It doesn't exactly load the data initially, but the "add data" button works, so I'm going to use a for loop and `push` to get the new data in there!

Comment: Yeah, I just did a minimum change.  If you want I could update it to use and object that is closer to your json.

Comment: The main thing is that I get a second dataset loaded into it, I've [done this so far](http://plnkr.co/edit/atRbp9w0uJIFzwJAysqF?p=preview) which is looping through and logging to the console, but not changing the source dataset yet

Comment: so that when the new data is applied it's immediately shown in the grid

Comment: I seen I had employee not employed so that last column was not loading, I fixed that.  I took a look at the approach you are taking and you are headed in a bad direction (went down the same path when I first started on this).  Take another look at my plunker example.

Comment: so final answer w/ my typo fixed: http://plnkr.co/edit/aEP3TvqYo0XaT58hMNGJ?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

One additional piece that I figured out with the help of Kevin Sage's answer and the plunker example...  If you are using the backward-compatible "field" attribute the swapping does not work properly when there are field name overlaps between the two sets of column definitions.  The column headers and the column widths are not rendered properly in this case.  Using the "name" attribute of the column definition corrects this.

```
    $scope.swapData = function() {
  if ($scope.gridOpts.data === data1) {
    $scope.gridOpts.columnDefs = [
      { field:'firstName' },
      { field:'lastName' },
      { field:'company' },
      { field:'employee' }
    ];
    $scope.gridOpts.data = data2;
    //punk column changes to employee
  }
  else {
    $scope.gridOpts.columnDefs = [
      { field:'firstName' },
      { field:'lastName' },
      { field:'company' },
      { field:'punk' }
    ];
    $scope.gridOpts.data = data1;
    //employee column changes to punk
  }
};
```

Example here: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jkEkn3LevMCm9LNVfYEk?p=preview)

Comment: Yeah - totally breaks when using field instead. Weird! Maybe `field` isn't so backward compatible after all

Comment: It looks like the changes made to the ui-grid scripting today have actually fixed this issue.  The plunker above began functioning correctly this afternoon.

Comment: ui-grid is REALLY cool that way. isn't the first time that has happened for issues I've had over the past couple months.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
$http.get('url').success(function(res) {
// clear data
gridOptions.data.length = 0;
// update data in next digest 
$timeout(function() {
gridOptions.data = res;
});
});
```